# JButton floating

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a JFrame which contains 5 JPanels.
The layout is something like that :
[image]

In the last panel (panel 5) , I have 5 buttons. I set the FlowLayout to right so they are aligned as I want them to be.

The problem is that I would like to move them down a little bit.

This is what I have as code:

```
    panel = new JPanel();
    gestBoutton = new FlowLayout();
    gestBoutton.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
```

I thought of making the 4th panel bigger so I can force them to push down but didn't work. panel 4 is a table.

Thank you

Comment: Do you intend to add anyone else to the panel? You could us a GridBagLayout; an EmptyBorder or a combination of different things based on your over all needs

Comment: @pateto777 the buttons in the panel 5

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok i will give the emptyborder a try ! thank you

Comment: As @pateto777 said, you need to clarify what you want to change. I'm guessing your flow layout probably isn't really what you want: I'd guess you really want a Box layout with line layout (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html); you can get finer vertical control by embedding your buttons in another JPanel and moving it around using a Spring layout or another Box layout.

Comment: I agree with @JerryAndrews

Answer (score 0):

You may create an appropriate an `Border` for your buttons. There is a `BorderFactory` that provides the creation of space borders: `static Border  createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)`. Then you just have to set the border of your components with `setBorder` of `JComponent`:

```
myButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,0,0,0));
```